# Reverting to old Google Cloud SDK shell version

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a Java project into Google App Engine from Eclipse and am blocked by JSPs.
Everything JSP makes my app not capable of deploying due to "'utf8' codec can't decode byte" error.
Not trying to insert any strange (not UTF-8) character, everything Eclipse is set to UTF-8.
Tried to send archives which were OK with the Google App Engine Tools for Eclipse (soon to be deprecated), won't deploy.
I've seen threads regarding reverting the Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin to previous version (1.58 seemed to avoid a few problems) being a possible solution to these recent errors but I have a problem installing, the batch just tells me "Install will exit" ?!
Tried to uninstall previous (latest) versions before, made sure I was launching the bundled-python batch, still not capable of installing an old version of the Google Cloud SDK shell.
Would be glad if anybody had any suggestion at what makes my install fail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

There are a few ways you can get older version of Google Cloud SDK.

1. Download [versioned archive](https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-sdk-release)

   - (If you are on windows) Grab `google-cloud-sdk-XXX.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python.zip` file.
   - Unzip it to `some\dir`
   - Add `some\dir\google-cloud-sdk\bin` directory to your system path
   - Restart your command prompt (or other apps which depend on gcloud) and run for example `gcloud info`, it should be fully functional installation, no need to run `install.bat`.
2. Alternatively, use existing SDK installation and `gcloud` component manager to go back to previous versions. For example

   ```
   gcloud components update --version 158.0.0
   ```

Answer (score 3):

target by version number using apt-get :

```
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=294.0.0-0
```

Comment: This didn't work for me